# Assessment of Geospatial Analysis and Poisson GLM Modeling for Accident Frequency with Cluster-Based Features

Tags: generalized-linear-model, k-means

I have a serious doubt about the quality of this approach:

Firstly, a geospatial analysis was conducted using accident frequency and wind speed data to segment the map of a country into clusters using the K-Means algorithm.

Subsequently, a GLM Regression (Poisson GLM) was used to explain accident frequency by using the clusters created earlier as explanatory variables (along with other exogenous variables).

What do think about it ? Thanks